# bootstrap confirmation is not working in partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, bootstrap-confirmation

I am working in one project with ASP.NET MVC having bootstrap, jquery and I have one main page inside that I have bind one partial view.

I have used [bootstrap.confirmation](http://bootstrap-confirmation.js.org/) in my application and it is working fine in all the main pages but when I try to implement in partial view html, it is not working.

My Code:

**HTML**

```
<a class="tooltips deleteOrg" data-container="body" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="confirmation" data-original-title="Delete organization" data-id="@organization.Id">
    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document.body).on('confirmed.bs.confirmation', '.deleteOrg', function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('[data-toggle=confirmation]').confirmation({
  rootSelector: '[data-toggle=confirmation]',
  onConfirm: function() {
   var id= $(this).data('id');
   alert(id);
  },
  buttons: [
    {
      class: 'btn btn-primary',
      label:"yes",
      icon:"glyphicon glyphicon-ok"
    },
    {
      class: 'btn btn-danger',
      label:"no",
      icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mistic100-Bootstrap-Confirmation/2.4.0/bootstrap-confirmation.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<a class="tooltips deleteOrg" data-container="body" data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="confirmation" data-original-title="Delete organization" data-id="test">
   Click
</a>
```

Comment: my pleasure and can you help me little bit I want to change the background color of yes and no how can I do this?

Comment: which element of the background color do you change?

Comment: I want to set background color of Yes and No only

Comment: No no sir you understand different way sir I want to set background color of yes and no or can say set class of that html part

Comment: <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-apply="confirmation"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Yes</a>  This is HTML of Yes I want to set btn-success class rather than the btn-primary here.

Comment: Unfortunately I got it wrong. I changed the code. Is this your answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162332/discussion-between-3-rules-and-farhad-bagherlo).

Comment: The code is running here but at my end it remains the same no change sir. It's ok sir you have given me the answer that is fine for me thanks a lot